# mat-autocomplete FormGroup required input issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

Well i have been trying to add `mat-autocomplete` to my form, and when finally things started to work for me this little issue popped as a pain in the back which is considered a stopper in my from.

I want the `mat-autocomplete` input to be required and it is required. But the problem is when i insert a value in the Input the form does not change to be valid it keeps giving me that Nationality is required even when i added a value to it. and i can't move on to the next horizontal step.

I tried to figure out why but i failed, i feel that the solution will turn to be a dummy one but working for long hours will make clear things blurry as y'all know.

so help guys

Here is my `<mat-form-field>`

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pl-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
    <input matInput placeholder="Nationality *" aria-label="Nationality *" formControlName="nationalitySelect"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="nationalitySelect" required>
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let nationality of filteredNationalities | async" (onSelectionChange)="nationalityOnChange($event,nationality)"
                [value]="nationality.name">
                <span>{{nationality.name}}</span>
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    <mat-error>Nationality is required!</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

And here is my typescript code

```
personalDetailsStep: FormGroup;
nationalitySelect: FormControl = new FormControl();

ngOnInit(): void {

    // Horizontal Stepper form steps
    this.personalDetailsStep = this._formBuilder.group({
        nationalitySelect: ['', Validators.required],
    });
}

filterNationalities() {
    let me = this;
    me.filteredNationalities =  me.personalDetailsStep.controls["nationalitySelect"].valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(nationality => nationality ? this._filteredNationalities(nationality) : this.nationalities.slice())
    );
}

private _filteredNationalities(value: string): Observable<any>[]{
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.nationalities.filter(nationality => nationality.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
}
nationalityOnChange(e, value){
    let me = this;
    if(e.isUserInput){
        me.newEmployee.NationalityId = value.id;
    }
}
```

> Please note that i sent you a part of my whole code in that specific
>   component so if you see any missing thing just let me know. i tried my
>   best to show everything you will need to help

Thank you in advacne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is;

HTML file:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pl-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
    <input matInput placeholder="Nationality *" aria-label="Nationality *" formControlName="nationalitySelect"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let nationality of filteredNationalities | async" (onSelectionChange)="nationalityOnChange($event,nationality)"
                [value]="nationality.name">
                <span>{{nationality.name}}</span>
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    <mat-error>Nationality is required!</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

typescript file:

```
personalDetailsStep: FormGroup;
nationalitySelect: FormControl = new FormControl();

ngOnInit(): void {

    // Horizontal Stepper form steps
    this.personalDetailsStep = this._formBuilder.group({
        nationalitySelect: this.nationalitySelect,
    });
}

filterNationalities() {
    let me = this;
    me.filteredNationalities =  me.nationalitySelect.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(nationality => nationality ? this._filteredNationalities(nationality) : this.nationalities.slice())
    );
}

private _filteredNationalities(value: string): Observable<any>[]{
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.nationalities.filter(nationality => nationality.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
}
nationalityOnChange(e, value){
    let me = this;
    if(e.isUserInput){
        me.newEmployee.NationalityId = value.id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<div [formGroup]="personalDetailsStep">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pl-sm-8" fxFlex="50">
    <input matInput placeholder="Nationality *" 
                    aria-label="Nationality *" 
                    formControlName="nationalitySelect"
                    [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let nationality of filteredNationalities | async" 
                    (onSelectionChange)="nationalityOnChange($event,nationality)"
                    [value]="nationality.name">
            <span>{{nationality.name}}</span>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    <mat-error>Nationality is required!</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work. i figured the solution i will post in a while